# INSERT INTO.... SELECT ...FROM... can have additional blank row?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Below is the sample query, trying to understand possibility of case if it can happen in TSQL Script.

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable
(
    Id, 
    SomeName, 
    SomeLevel, 
    SomeDate
)
OUTPUT Inserted.Id, Inserted.SomeName, Inserted.SomeLevel, Inserted.SomeDate INTO @SomeTable
SELECT 
    Id, 
    SomeName, 
    @SomeLevel as SomeLevel, 
    SomeDate
FROM
    SomeTableSource WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE
    Id = @SourceID;
```

The case is, can above statement capable to insert blank record from select?
Now what that mean is....

The number of rows returned by below select is ten but inserted records are eleven, and one row from all eleven is blank.

```
SELECT 
        Id, 
        SomeName, 
        @SomeLevel as SomeLevel, 
        SomeDate
    FROM
        SomeTableSource WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE
        Id = @SourceID;
```

If that can happen then what is the reason?

Comment: Well, why are you using `NOLOCK`, for starters? Is that the turbo button? It can cause [all kinds of unexpected results](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/). See if you can reproduce the problem *without it*. Also, where is `@SomeTable` defined? Is it possible you insert a row after it is created? Can you get 11 rows by using `OUTPUT` *without* the `INTO`?

Comment: Is that your real query?

Comment: There is nothing in that setup that would insert an extra null record are you sure there is not a null record already in @SomeTable or added later?

Comment: @AaronBertrand SomeTable table variable is defined and it is not having blank row before insert, why nolock? thats how it was written to have dirty read by someone. Its not easily reproducible in single user mode I can give try removing nolock in load test

Comment: "it was written to have dirty read" - uh, what?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am trying to hunt a problem, the query I share is derived from original to get blank row with insert. As you pointed NOLOCK in select "turbo button" :)) want to understand will that introduce blank row?

Comment: Sure, you can read a row twice, you can read a row mid-update or mid-insert, who knows? NOLOCK says "I don't give a crap about accuracy, just give me potentially wrong results *with less locking*."

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for the input, I will give load test to recreate the issue.

Comment: Why do you need load test?   Yes NOLOCK can produce a null row.

Comment: @Paparazzi I can stretch transaction in debug environment but that will not be 100% proof with business transactions, to get realistic application usage picture with related result, I prefer laod test :)

Comment: What part of NOLOCK can produce a null row or bad data is not clear?  NOLOCK is not a realistic business transaction.

Comment: @Paparazzi the underlying TSQL is part of SP and SP has bunch of data insertion operation, target table is used by many other SPs to perform write, since only live app has this issue[ which also happening in rare], the only way to build concurrency with business transactions is load test. Hopefully you will understand where I am targeting to reproduce with existing code having TURBO BUTTON :) NoLock

Comment: null is challenging... if you put at the where clause isnull(Id,'') = isnull(@SourceID,'') and try it. this is if your @sourceid can even be null.